# Generic type with reference to one of its properties with different type

Tags: typescript

I want to have `Columns<T>` type which will reference to itself in one of it properties but with different `T` type.

`Columns<T>` is array of `ColumnDefinitionType<T>` union type.

```
type Columns<T> = ColumnDefinition<T>[];

type ColumnDefinition<T> = SubgridColumn<T> | Column<T>;
```

`Column<T>` is object type with one property

```
type Column<T> = {
    render: (item: T, rowIndex: number) => React.ReactNode;
};
```

`SubgridColumn<T>` has two properties

```
type SubgridColumn<T> = {
    subgridItems: ((item: T, rowIndex: number) => any[]) | any[];
    subgridColumns: Columns<any>;
};
```

At the moment `subgridItems` can be array of any type or function that returns array of any type and `subgridColumns` is `Columns<any>` type.

I want to type `Subgrid<T, N>` where `N` replaces any type

```
type SubgridColumn<T, N> = {
    subgridItems: ((item: T, rowIndex: number) => N[]) | N[];
    subgridColumns: Columns<N>;
};
```

Usage of this type would be

```
type Cargo = { locationFrom: string; models: Model[] };
type Model = { modelName: string; parts: Part[] };
type Part = { partName: string; partPrice: number };
type UsageCountry = { countryName: string; contintent: string };

const countries: UsageCountry[] = [
    { countryName: 'Ireland', contintent: 'Europe' },
    { countryName: 'USA', contintent: 'North America' },
];

const cargos: Cargo[] = [
    {
        locationFrom: 'London',
        models: [
            {
                modelName: 'Audi',
                parts: [
                    { partName: 'Spoiler', partPrice: 599 },
                    { partName: 'Wheel', partPrice: 199 },
                ],
            },
            { modelName: 'Subaru', parts: [{ partName: 'Tint', partPrice: 99 }] },
        ],
    },
    { locationFrom: 'Paris', models: [{ modelName: 'VW', parts: [{ partName: 'Muffler', partPrice: 159 }] }] },
];
```

Bellow is columns with type `Columns<Cargo>`. It is an array of `ColumnDefinition<Cargo>` which can be `Column<Cargo>` or `SubgridColumn<Cargo>`. When it is latter type, I want for `subgridColumns` to infer type from subgridItems type.
So if `subgridItems` return type is `Model[]` then `subgridColumns` should be of type `Columns<Model>`

```
const columns: Columns<Cargo> = [
    { render: cargo => cargo.locationFrom },
    {
        subgridItems: cargo => cargo.models,
        subgridColumns: [
            { render: model => model.modelName },
            {
                subgridItems: model => model.parts,
                subgridColumns: [{ render: part => part.partName }, { render: part => part.partPrice }],
            },
            {
                subgridItems: model => (model.modelName === 'Subaru' ? countries : []),
                subgridColumns: [
                    {
                        render: country => country.countryName,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

You can also see than `subgridItems` function, when `Columns<Model>` type is used, returns countries array of type `UsageCountry` which is unrelated to `Model` or `Cargo` type so basically return type of `subgridItems` (or subgridItems type if it is not a function but array) should not be tied to properties of type `T` in `Columns<T>`

How to achieve this because issue with current setup is that return type of `subgridItems` is always any and not safe to use.

Comment: Why is `{ items: item => item.alternatives }` in there? Is that a typo? This question is confusing enough to me without typos so I hope you can [edit] to make it clear what's going on.  Crucially it would be great if you could spell out what you would expect `N` to be for particular `T` types.  Like, what do you want the entries of the `columns` prop of  `GridProps<Cargo>` to be?   Also, is there a reason why you've got `type Columns<T> = ColumnDefinition<T>[];` instead of just using `ColumnDefinition<T>[]`? The more indirection in the code, the harder it is to follow.

Comment: (see prev comment) I strongly suspect that if you say "`N` can be anything" then you are looking for [existentially quantified generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) which TS doesn't directly support (and neither do most languages). (See [ms/TS#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).) You can *encode* them in TS, but it involves some Promise-like callback shuttling, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NdDxnN). I could show how one might *use* them, if you can [edit] to show how you plan to use a `GridProps<Cargo>`.

Comment: @jcalz, added use case and changed some typing for better readability. I had a feeling that subRowColumn type can't be anything, but what about if it won't accept N[] as a type, but only type of properties of T, basically like in an example. So subRowItems and subRowColumns must infer type of T properties and that property must be of an array type?

Comment: @jcalz, I came up with solution based on your promise-like callback. I edited issue and posted result. Please feel free to correct it in accordance to my usage case and post your answer. Thank you so much

Comment: Hmm, generally speaking one would not put the answer inside the question, or to say "I came up with" it without attribution. My plan here was to see if I could come up with a union type that would take the place of `N` but I'm not sure how to proceed at all now.

Comment: (see prev comment) like, given your prev description I'd say maybe something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAaq8m) would work (although it's not clear what you want to see if there are *multiple* array props in a type, showing use cases is good) but only if you roll back to a more suitable version of the question. Let me know what you want to do here.

Comment: @jcalz, sorry for not mentioning you. Mentioned now. Latest solution with ArraysProps was exactly what I needed in specific situation, but I have places in my project where I will implement your promise-like callback solution too. So I will use latter one as it covers all scenarios.

Comment: Okay, but the solution doesn't belong in the question, it belongs as an answer post. And if you're going to write an answer, it should have an explanation as for *why* it works and where it comes from, which means you'd need to talk about existential types. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is meant not just for the original question asker but for future readers and it should be like a FAQ: a well-defined question that someone else might run into, and an answer with an explanation. Right now this is at best useful to just you. I'll disengage now unless I see something more suitable here.

Comment: @jcalz, thank you for notes. I edited my question to address my initial issue and removed any specific use case answers. Feel free to make some notes if needed and post answer if you think that question is submitted well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a type like `type SubgridColumn<T, N> = ⋯`, and you want to write

```
type ColumnDefinition<T> = SomeSubgridColumn<T> | Column<T>;
```

where `SomeSubgridColumn<T>` is a `SubgridColumn<T, N>` for *some* type `N` you don't know or care about.

---

When you find yourself needing a type like `F<N>` for *some* type `N` you don't know, then you are reaching for so-called [*existentially quantified generics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) (also called *existential types*).  You want to say "there *exists* a type `N` such that the resulting type is `F<N>`".  But TypeScript, like most languages with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), only has *universally-quantified generics*, which mean that `F<N>` has to work *for all* types `N`.  There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](//https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) for existential types, but for now they are not directly supported.

So if you want an existential type, you'll need to work around it somehow.

---

The easiest approach is to just use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) as the type argument to replace the existential generic:

```
type SomeSubgridColumn<T> = SubgridColumn<T, any>
```

which is the same as your original version of `SubgridColumn`.  This is, as I said, very easy. But it doesn't accurately represent existential types, and it isn't type-safe.

---

On the other end of the spectrum you can *encode* existential generic types using universal generic types, via a `Promise`-like structure.  The idea is that instead of an `F<N>`, you get a function which takes a callback that accepts an `F<N>`. You don't have direct access to the `F<N>` value, just a black box containing it.  Since you don't know what `N` is, you have to make sure your callback would work for *all* `N`.  Existentials and universals are duals of each other when you change the direction of the flow of data, in the same way that [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) are duals of each other.  (Indeed, you can think of an existential as an "infinite union" whereas a universal is an "infinite intersection".)

Here's how it looks:

```
type SomeSubgridColumn<T> =
    <R>(cb: <N>(sc: SubgridColumn<T, N>) => R) => R;
```

So if I give you a `SomeSubgridColumn<T>`, you can pass it a callback that has to accept a `SubgridColumn<T, N>` for all possible `N`, that returns whatever type `R` you'd like.  And when you do that, you get a value of type `R`.  So you put your callback into the black box, the callback is run on the hidden value, and then the result is passed out to you.

It's easy enough to put a `SubgridColumn<T, N>` into a `SomeSubgridColumn<T>` box:

```
const someSubgridColumn = <T, N>(
    sc: SubgridColumn<T, N>
): SomeSubgridColumn<T> => cb => cb(sc);
```

And you'll need to wrap your data accordingly:

```
const columns: Columns<Cargo> = [
    { render: cargo => cargo.locationFrom },
    someSubgridColumn({
        subgridItems: cargo => cargo.models,
        subgridColumns: [
            { render: model => model.modelName },
            someSubgridColumn({
                subgridItems: model => model.parts,
                subgridColumns: [
                    { render: part => part.partName },
                    { render: part => part.partPrice }],
            }),
            someSubgridColumn({
                subgridItems: model => (
                    model.modelName === 'Subaru' ? countries : []
                ),
                subgridColumns: [
                    {
                        render: country => country.countryName,
                    },
                ],
            }),
        ],
    }),
];
```

On the other hand, consuming a `SomeSubgridColumn<T>` is a little more complex, much like consuming a `Promise`. It's in a box and you have to pass it a callback.  For example: imagine you want to take a `Columns<Cargo>` and map each element to the number of `subgridColumns` it has.  With your original structure you'd maybe write

```
columns.map(cd => "render" in cd ? 0 : cd.subgridColumns.length);
```

But you can't do that, since `cd` doesn't have `subgridColumns` directly. It's inside the box.  So you have to write:

```
columns.map(cd => "render" in cd ? 0 : cd(sc => sc.subgridColumns.length));
```

which works.

This approach is a more complicated than the version with `any`, but it has the advantage of actually being type safe.

---

Finally, it's important to note that if it turns out that the `N` you don't care about can only be one of a reasonably small finite set of types, then you can dispense with existentials and use unions instead.  If `N` can only be `A` or `B` or `C`, then you can often just write `A | B | C`.  In your use case you were mentioning that `N` might only be those property types of `T` that are arrays.  You can compute those:

```
type ArrayElements<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U : never
}[keyof T];

type AEC = ArrayElements<Cargo>;
// type AEC = Model
```

And then `N` can possibly be replaced with that:

```
type SomeSubgridColumn<T> = SubgridColumn<T, ArrayElements<T>>
```

although you might want that to be [distributed over unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in `ArrayElements<T>`:

```
type SomeSubgridColumn<T> = 
  ArrayElements<T> extends infer N ? N extends any ?
    SubgridColumn<T, N> : never : never;
```

I won't digress further explaining that much, but presumably if `N` for a given `T` can be `A | B | C` you want `SomeSubgridColumn<T>` to be `SubgridColumn<T, A> | SubgridColumn<T, B> | SubgridColumn<T, C>` instead of `SubgridColumn<T, A | B | C>`.  This may or may not suffice for a given use case. It's more complicated than `any` but has less weird inversion than encoding existentials.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIGED2AbArgWwHYB4AqA+WAXlgG9hZLYAnaTAE2moC5YAKAS1GnVdwBoaiAO4BJBtAAerTBgBGTAJTFCAQ0zgA3MAC+2sFDgBlVHIDm1DvSRoseQQDlCJclVgBnUxauju6d6xsnH58gtQi4ozSsLLoCtTKRIQOANoAusoAPrCpadpunuaW1igYmAEIpVju2E7aeiAQMLBGiOjQJkVWNmV4zhRU2ABK+GwAxnKstaPuY6yd3iW2OAI5+ImEQxuwQ-pjiOWgHm0dXsU9WMSw9mtsA5Sz82fdVSuO+MCK8ycL5699KlgE0BEzYs0U+gMzQu5QBJBhABFoAAzDiYLgcA59dL6JpwREotEYrEEK6tdq-F7LAHZGF9fRo7jUZGqMb41TUMyIMiwZCIMaqUCYzAAMXCvA8oEsmDMmlg6EQjGQFQAsoroMh0rAGoymCy2bA1UqeQqlQ5VO1WO4pWjZbBIBzQBUAAqOrU6zBM-VwV3UI6ke2O82WyXSu0Ov3OyxsmTyJja7S65msuAAVXcqjM0CQqE91HAPP2ual4GD0CtNplcv2nt1norYYTIBr1qBiGLlmgFXTmez7bz4C1JBS90L-ZLZdYAHJRLRkOp6FPBDWhZ66KBpwBRVDhGBT7X8UcBosDyewKepowAQSXbdra-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-djVAA-Q23+KwIOEHcTOkU9mWY0Qgvnk51AubAAD8bYdhwXawBxaRwwh1OKwU0OdVdPPKSrSm40wrAniWILjvmk0G-mZY05rEU82FVnK5RttUFT-76AA9K7bVlO4R2qJA4z0ICABEuvUIHsBokCAeSwADHLkeTSzMPTXQZigK+ELAC2KDQNNiBmNzVD7O1Pt+2MAfjcHg1MGHEdlxLsCx-r9BgmMgKzAnavF8JMpp4oiifPomBqe4DoGqm6IHGQo54h+1DUKo4CbsJ7SejUpIuNdKQANLh5gsAANbQOAiDIrAuBpHw2-BVI3AMO4A2qDhmDIAWnCYMi8apooWqS6mceYNAAAbkwcKKRD7H1PuffIVAZ5Xk3PAK4V454LyXjwdcXVRr4GgZQd2sBYHwKuEaDUIA3Az3JKcL6dJ16z3novZe6CAQ30GvfNEH9qA5Hrg4WATC76wHUAWcW11KTfTeGsOW10AHAPYTIIBTB9A6CAA)

Comment: Today I implemented your solutions and what worked best for my case scenario - your last ArrayElements<T> implementation which is distributed over unions as you mentioned SubgridColumn<T, A> | SubgridColumn<T, B>...The only issue I still need to workaround is for SubgridColumn<T, N> N is not inferred and requires to be explicitly typed. I've put an [example](https://tsplay.dev/wOK9rw) if you want to look into it.

Comment: because `Model` has both `parts` and `countries` and so you need to specify which one it is, the compiler can't infer it for you.